# How to post multiple data through $.ajax to Codeigniter controller method

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

this is the method I want to send data to it

```
function get_lesson($reshte,$poodeman){
        $this->load->model('dropdown_model');
        header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');
        echo(json_encode($this->dropdown_model->get_lessons($reshte,$poodeman)));
    }
```

and this is the `get_lessens()` function in the model file.

```
  function get_lessons($reshte = null, $poodeman=NULL){
          $this->db->select('rlessid, title');

          if($reshte != NULL AND $poodeman!= NULL ){
              $this->db->where('reshteid', $reshte);
              $this->db->where('poodemanid', $poodeman);
          }

          $query = $this->db->get('tbllessons_root');

          $lessons = array();

          if($query->result()){
              foreach ($query->result() as $lesson) {
                  $lessons[$lesson->rlessid] = $lesson->title;
              }

          return $lessons;
          }else{
              return FALSE;
          }
    }
```

and this is my ajax call at the view file

```
var reshteid = $('#reshte').val();
 var poodemanid = $('#poodemanha').val();

$.ajax({
     type:"POST",
     url:"http://localhost/crud-grocery/index.php/examples/get_lesson/",//+reshte+"/"+poodeman,
     data: "reshte="+reshteid+"&poodeman="+poodemanid,
     success: function(lessons)
     {
        $.each(lessons,function(rlessid,title){
          var opt = $('<option />');
        opt.val(rlessid);
        opt.text(title);
        $('#lessons').append(opt);
        });
    }
```

});

as you see I am trying to chain options in the form 
but The problem comes up when I try to post (send) two parameters to the controller method 
any idea?

Comment: so ajax is not posting the data...? Or the problem is something else...?

Comment: it sends it when I post one parameter to the controller method, but it wont work when I include second paramether as post data. :(

Comment: you need to get POST values in your controller function not as parameters, since you are using POST method in Ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, you need to get **POST** values not as parameters:

```
//in controller
function get_lessons(){
...
//get POST values
$reshte = $this->input->post('reshte');
$poodeman = $this->input->post('poodeman');
```

Comment: That is true, I should go to sleep before i ask such questions again.

Comment: Happens sometimes, Glad to know you got it.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass data as a javascript object literal:

```
...
data: {
  reshte: reshteid,
  poodeman: poodemanid
}
....
```

Comment: this is anther type of defining post data